# How to auto highlight buffer or region in web-mode?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

I'm using web-mode 13.1.25, but was until today on 12.x with the same issue.

It seems I need to continually choose `Highlight buffer (C-c C-h)` as otherwise, certain functions misbehave.

These steps demonstrate the problem:

1. Adding `<p>Foo` into the body...

`<body>
    <p>Foo
 </body>`

2. When beginning to type the closing tag

`<body>
    <p>Foo</
 </body>`

3. It completes to the wrong tag.

`<body>
    <p>Foo</body>
 </body>`

If, however, I type `<p>Foo`, then type `C-C C-h` to update highlighting, then when typing the closing tag it auto-completes correctly.

Is it possible to have the current region or the entire buffer's syntax highlighting auto-updated when entering text or a tag?

Is there some setting I'm missing? Is there a recommended workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: It turned out that having `(setq whitespace-line-column 80000)` seemed to cause the issue.

Commenting that out enabled normal behaviour.

See https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/730#issuecomment-241332750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `(setq whitespace-line-column 80000)` in my init.el files turned out to be an incompatible configuration.

Commenting that out enabled webmode to work as expected.

See this [github issue](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/730#issuecomment-241332750) for further discussion.

Comment: I believe you can accept your own answer.  This is very useful.